# iOS - How to disable the Firebase caching?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made delete on post object in firebase node.

But when I query for post objects , previously cached post objects are shown.

I am not getting refreshed data from firebase.

Question:
Is there a way to stop firebase caching and get the refreshed data from firebase in iOS?

MY Code:

```
self.firPostRef.child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.value is NSNull { completion(nil) }
        else {
            //print(snapshot.debugDescription)
            let postids = Array((snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]).keys)

            print(postids)
            completion(postids)

        }
    }) { (error) in
        debugPrint("error occured in getting all comments -" + error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

use observeSingleEventOfType, reference.keepSynced(true). It refreshes data once this code is executed.

Use observeEventOfType. This will always keep your data in sync and will execute again as soon as you made changes.

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

Just disable the firebase caching using the following code:

```
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().keepSynced(false)
```

Ta da ..

Comment: How can I get this working in TypeScript for Firecast